# Fill Ring tool problem

Tags: qgis, polygon, editing, ring

In the help file it says
"*Draw a new polygon over the existing feature: QGIS adds a ring to its geometry (like if you used the addRing Add Ring tool) and creates a new feature whose geometry matches the ring (like if you traced over the interior boundaries with the capturePolygon Add polygon feature tool).*"

But the new polygon dont matches the ring and in my eyes Fill Ring and Add polygon feature are doing the same

What am I missing how can I fill a hole in a polygon without exactly tracing the interior boundaries? Is ring and hole not the same?

Comment: Fill ring bores a hole into an existing polygon and creates a new polygon that fills the hole by the same. But do you mean that you have already a hole in your polygon? Ring is not the same as hole because all rings are not holes. In a polygon the first ring is the outer boundary and the next rings are holes.

Comment: Yes I have a hole in an polygon och sometimes between two polygons that I am trying to fill with a new polygon and I thought that "fill ring-tool" was my solution